# Flutter DropDownButton to change page body

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a UI like this where there is a drop down button and below that the space which should show only the widget I choose from the DropdownButton.

[image: DropdownButton]

The Widgets are in different classes like this

```
List<Widget> contactItems = [
    RecentContactsScreen(),
    Contacts(),
    AgentsList(),
    OwnersList(),
];
```

I need to know how can I implement in a way to achieve this task.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the `DropdownButton` has a property called `onChange`, inside the function you can navigate to the screen

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget _build(index) {
switch (index) {
  case 0:
    return Container();
  case 1:
    return Container();
  default:
    return Container();
} }
```

pass the index or create a global variable and change it onChange of drop down. replace the Container with your UI.

Comment: please accept the answer by clicking check mark and up vote. so that another user can know the right answer as well.